# Excel formula to Count within clusters of rows (defined by same value) and values for the adjacent column is the same for the given cluster

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet containing a large dataset and would need a formula to achieve the following (see image attached):

[image: Stackoverflow Excel Request]

The objective is to have Excel perform the following:

1- Identify and cluster the rows, based on identical values in col. A (in this case, we should have clusters "Alpha, Bravo, Charlie")

2- Inside every cluster, return a new count (called, for example, "Individual count") if all the values in col. B for the cluster are "Individual"

3- If any row contains value "Entity" in col. B for a given cluster, return a new count (called, for example, "Entity count").

Based on the above example, the output should be as:

Individual Count = 1 (only Alpha contains only "Individual" associated to its rows)
Entity Count = 2 (both Bravo and Charlie contain, at least, "Entity" associated to its rows)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Have you tried using pivot table? From what I understand you want to count two things: 1) number of distinct names that only has individual; 2) number of distinct names that has more than or other than individual. If that's true you could use a helper column (or maybe a couple helper columns) to solve your question if you do not mind using helper columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, Terry - I will explore this approach and come back to you with the outcome. Cheers!

Comment: @ Faraday: Should an Excel Guru answer with a more sensibly short formula, then please use that formula. ( I will learn from his answer as well ).

Answer (score 0):

The following formula is indeed very lengthy and took quite a while to arrive at.There were so many variables to account for.I tried the Frequency function, but could not get it to work with the text cells, including variations of other functions.The formula can be placed in cell C1 and filled down as far as needed:

=IF(IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Bravo"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoIndividual",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoIndividual",1,""),0)+IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Bravo"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoEntity",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoEntity",1,""),0)+IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Alpha"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaIndividual",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaIndividual",1,""),0)+IFERROR(IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Alpha"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaEntity",1,""),0)),"")*IFERROR(SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaEntity",1,"")),"")+IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Charlie"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieIndividual",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieIndividual",1,""),0)+IFERROR(IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Charlie"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieEntity",1,""),0)),"")*IFERROR(SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieEntity",1,"")),"")<1,"",IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Bravo"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoIndividual",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoIndividual",1,""),0)+IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Bravo"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoEntity",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="BravoEntity",1,""),0)+IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Alpha"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaIndividual",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaIndividual",1,""),0)+IFERROR(IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Alpha"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaEntity",1,""),0)),"")*IFERROR(SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="AlphaEntity",1,"")),"")+IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Charlie"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieIndividual",1,""),0))/SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieIndividual",1,""),0)+IFERROR(IF(AND(A1<>A2,A1="Charlie"),SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieEntity",1,""),0)),"")*IFERROR(SUM(IF(A$1:A$10&B$1:B$10="CharlieEntity",1,"")),""))

Comment: Roger, many thanks for this amount of effort, I will test it and come back to you. As you mentioned, I will definitely let you know directly if anyone may provide a more compact solution. Many thanks, again.